# How to Horizontal with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am spanking new to jquery and am looking to learn. am reading "Mastering JQuery" and "JQuery: Novice to Ninja"

Been at getting my site to work a certain way for a several days and have gone thru many iterations all resulting in hours of frustration.

I am trying to work up a horizontal site that not just hides horizontal scroll, but completely dumps it even when users are trying to increase the font size.

Here is the prime example of what I would love, love, love the site to look like [INSPIRATION SITE](http://www.secondstory.com/studio/expertise)

How would I go about doing this with my site (link below)?

For the life of me I can't get my site [HERE](http://universalpartnership.org) to do this. Been searching support forums for weeks trying to get some support and advice on this and have been very unsuccessful so far. Most of the development so far has been from research, googling, reading, and pure experimentation.

I would like to do two main things: 1. make the whole site a fixed width or auto 100% (ideally like the nav bar on my site) AND 2. how can I make each section a page so the nav jumps will be smoother like the inspiration site?

It would be super great to get some support, advice and/or direction on how I can achieve this using Jquery. What plugins would be best? And anything else I might be overlooking.

I've attached the html. it's ugly, I know, and everything and then some as far as coding is there so please forgive me!

Comment: if you remove the height:625px horizontal scroll can be removed

Comment: sorry, one more ?, this applies to all viewpoints?

Comment: yes, and i found i more problem with image that you used image as a border is not good enuff so my advide is that use i mage till the up small logo and after that create image 1px long and width according to your border and repeat(repeat-y) it and also use height 100%

Comment: OK, cool. How do I do that? is it the BG image, the purple one, for the nav? the image is set as a border instead of a BG image? I think I get what you are saying and am gonna give it a go! thx so much again! You RAWK! any thoughts on the JQuery since? :)

Answer (score 1):

jScrollPane

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Best of luck.